# Proper method of performing multiple inserts of textual data into text widget as step through sqlite results?

Tags: sqlite, tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm attempting to extract multiple rows of textual data from SQLite and add tags to it to display in a Tk text widget.

If I were doing something similar in a browser, I would build the elements in a document fragment and then add the fragment to the DOM, as opposed to writing to the DOM multiple times. Is there an equivalent approach in Tk; or is it efficient to perform inserts repeatedly in the database results loop in Tcl that is equivalent to the sqlite3_step in the C API?

For example (where there may be up to a few hundred such rows returned by the query)

```
db1 eval {SELECT * FROM table ...} {
    .widget insert end $column_1 "tag_1 tag_x"
    .widget insert end $column_2 "tag_2 tag_y"
    .widget insert end $column_3\n "tag_3 tag_x"
}
```

Or, should one attempt to use something like `GROUP_CONCAT` in the SQL to build a single statement to evaluate in Tcl?

Thank you.

A more specific example is below.  The data for a single verse is made up of multiple rows in the database; and, most often, many verses will be extracted at once.  I need to tag the `strongs_no` column such that it can be styled as a superscript.

If I just select the rows, then there will be many inserts; but, if I use `group_concat` in the SQL, then I don't know how to add the tags.
If that were possible, there'd still be an insert for every verse returned.

```
book_no  chapter_no  verse_no  index_no  strongs_no  kjv_text        
-------  ----------  --------  --------  ----------  ----------------
1        1           1         1         H7225       In the beginning
1        1           1         2         H430        God             
1        1           1         3         H1254       created         
1        1           1         4         H853                        
1        1           1         5         H8064       the heaven      
1        1           1         6         H853        and             
1        1           1         7         H776        the earth.     

 
select group_concat( kjv_text || strongs_no, ' ') as kjv
from blb_kjv_text
where book_no=1
  and chapter_no=1
  and verse_no=1


kjv                                                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------
In the beginningH7225 GodH430 createdH1254 H853 the heavenH8064 andH853 the earth.H776
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to apply different tags to each span of text, it's probably easiest to use many `insert` calls. Individually, they're not very expensive (the measuring and rendering are the costly bits, but they're postponed until the application is idle so you don't really see the costs in most applications). If you're not inserting at the end, set your own custom mark (with default rightward gravity) and do the inserts at that; it has fewest surprises.

I really wouldn't do the `GROUP_CONCAT` in SQL unless there's some other query-related reason for doing so, as Tcl's extremely good at text manipulation.